# Geometry Nodes: How to get Object Rotation in Local space?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Object Info Node returns Transforms in World Space. How does one get Local Space Rotation? (relative to Parent)

Edit: The end goal is to reliably extract bone rotations by parenting/constraining some object to them, as there is no direct bone access currently.

Comment: _Object Info_ 'Original' returns the transforms in World Space. _Object Info_ 'Relative' returns the transforms in the modified object's space. Do you mean you want the info-d object in the space of a third-party parent that's not  the modified object?

Comment: @Robin Betts
Hi, thanks and sorry for a slow reply. 
"'Relative' returns the transforms in the modified object's space" - correct.
What I mean is I need the cordinates of a target object as they are stored in it, without conversions to other spaces (which, yes, in case of parenting is in the space of an object that is not the modified object).
Edit: To be clear, I'm trying to reliably extract bone rotations by parenting something else to them, as there is no bone access currently.

Comment: Hi, kivig! No problem, I've had to be away myself. I think it would pay off, if you copy-pasted your motivation into your original question Then folks could run a few tests on your use-case before answering, if they can.